# How to Delete The "Move to Dropbox" Entry In The Contextual Menu?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, context-menu

I have noticed recently that when I right click on a file/folder in Windows 7, the contextual menu brings up an entry entitled *Move to Dropbox* ( enabling one to send a selected file/folder to ones Dropbox folder on Windows, which will be automatically synchronized to their online Dropbox account).I haven't noticed this before, and I am guessing it coincides with the recent release of Dropbox Version 2.4.

At present I have no need for this entry, and would like to know how to remove it (either via comand prompt or other means) from the contextual menu and additionally how to add it again to the contextual menu (if so desired in the future) ?

Comment: Use CCleaner or ShellExView

Comment: @darthbith This is [not the way we like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) to answer/comment on questions. It is rude even if its a simple question for you

Comment: @nixda Thanks for the feedback. I've removed the comment since the answer below contains mostly the same information as the link I provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER).

Once downloaded and installed, open CCleaner.
On the left select '*Tools*' then '*Startup*' and select the tab '*Context Menu*'.
From there you can edit/disable the entries.

Alternatively you can downloaded a more advanced program called [ShellExView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).
*Please note: CCleaner is a lot easier to use but will not show all context menu entries.*

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I've never used ShellExView (but shall check it out). I am a fan of CCleaner as I use it quite often to get rid of debris on my PC.

Comment: @Simon No problem. I'm a fan of CCleaner as well. Please mark it as 'Answered' so others can see it too.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't want to install CCleaner, so I used instructions found at [intowindows.com](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-remove-move-to-dropbox-from-context-menu/). That site includes pictures, but superusers should be able to follow text directions. :) It's only 4 steps:

1. Exit Dropbox
2. Right-click the shortcut for Dropbox in your Windows Start menu and select Properties.
3. Add `--move-to-dropbox=False` to the end of the Target line, e.g. `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe /home --move-to-dropbox=False`
4. Click OK in the shortcut dialog.

Comment: Only /move-to-dropbox=False seems to be accepted (not with --). Also, this is a much better solution than the others because it keeps the Dropbox context menu available in the Dropbox folder (for defining sharing and whatnot).

Comment: Today on Win 10, this worked: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\Dropbox.exe" /home /move-to-dropbox=False`  in shortcut: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Dropbox

Answer (score 5):

I remove the Dropbox from context menu with this steps on Windows 10. 2018

- 1: Go to the dropbox Icon right click and select **open file location**
- 2: In this step, you must see the Dropbox.exe, right-click anywhere and open the **CMD** in this location -
- 3: On this location type this command `Dropbox --move-to-dropbox=False`

[image]

Comment: This works. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can run the following command

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.22.dll"
```

Replace `[username]` with the username of the windows account you are logged into to remove the context menu, as this is a per-user setting.

Comment: This did not work for me with "module dropboxext.22 failed to load"